# Image Update Exception

Tags: c#, image, exception, windows-phone-8

I am using the following code to update an image source and keep getting the exception.

```
String[] ParseLocationAndMessage = Shouts[0].Message.Split(',');
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://shout.somee.com/allimages/IVn1XSTZXShJG5UxrvLZCOGXolVHjR9WCzDag-WVLsjAtla.jpg"));

shoutImage1.Source = bitmap;

shoutmessage1.Text = ParseLocationAndMessage[0];
shoutlocation1.Text = ParseLocationAndMessage[1];
```

I have looked around quite a lot and found this is the best way to give image source, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what was the exact error message?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a cross-thread access exception? Try wrap your code inside a BeginInvoke ensuring the code is ran on the UI thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   // code
});
```

There's too little info really be sure what the problem is.
Does it always happen? How many images can your app hold - easily over 500? Where is your code called? Inside an async method? Do you use .ConfigureAwait(false) somewhere?
Tried setting breakpoints to see where the exception is raised?
If it is when you set the image source, then it's most likely a cross-thread exception.

Comment: the exception is raised at 
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://shout.somee.com/allimages/IVn1XSTZXShJG5UxrvLZCOGXolVHjR9WCzDag-WVLsjAtla.jpg"));

Comment: BitmapImage can only be instantiated on the UI thread, so it looks like a cross-thread issue.
Do you run your code in a Tasks.Run? Or use ConfigureAwait(false) before your code is called?

Comment: on which event should I bind my source to image?

Comment: i did it on page_load, is there any other event i can use?